# How to enable TNonblockingServer while I'm building Thrift 0.9.2

Tags: c++, linux, thrift

I'm trying to build up a thrift with version 0.9.2, here is my command that I executed:

```
sudo ./configure --with-boost=/usr/local/boost_1.58.0
```

It will succeeded, but I get a returned message like this:

```
thrift 0.9.2

Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building C (GLib) Library .... : yes
Building Java Library ........ : yes
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : yes
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : no
Building Lua Library ......... : yes

C++ Library:
   Build TZlibTransport ...... : yes
   Build TNonblockingServer .. : no
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt) .... : yes

Java Library:
   Using javac ............... : javac
   Using java ................ : java
   Using ant ................. : /usr/bin/ant

Python Library:
   Using Python .............. : /usr/bin/python

PHP Library:
   Using php-config .......... : 

Lua Library:
   Using Lua .............. : /usr/bin/lua

If something is missing that you think should be present,
please skim the output of configure to find the missing
component.  Details are present in config.log.
```

I've tried many ways to let the Build `TNonblockingServer` option be `YES` but I failed.

Comment: (1) no sudo required (2) configure produces logfile(s) which contain(s) all kinds of information. Did you check those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need libevent to be installed. Here are the relevant parts from `configure.ac`:

```
AX_LIB_EVENT([1.0])
have_libevent=$success
```

and

```
echo "   Build TNonblockingServer .. : $have_libevent"
```

It's also listed under the "language requirements" section [over here](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/):

> **Language requirements**
>
> **C++**
>
> - Boost 1.53.0
> - libevent (optional, **to build the nonblocking server**)
> - zlib (optional)

The minimum boost version is actually **1.54**, the website is slightly outdated regaring that point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have already solved this problem, you are right, it's because the libevent who cause this problem. After checking the log I see that the 0.9.2 version thrift need a >=1.0 version libevent so I install a latest version libevent and command "sudo ./configure --with-boost=/usr/local/boost_1.58.0 --with-libevent=/usr/local/libevent_2022 --without-qt4 --without-php" seems to work fine. Really thanks!!!!